# Express com TypeScript: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express.js

Estou tentando gerar as rotas da minha aplicação dinamicamente com o `Express.router()` utilizando TypeScript e Node, porém não funciona e não estou conseguindo entender o porquê.

Se alguém por favor souber oque está ocorrendo me dê uma explicação sobre ou algum lugar que possa consultar, não achei nada parecido na documentação =(

```js
router[route.method](route.path, route.handler, route.middleware)
```

O código acima funciona normalmente no Node.js porém no TypeScript ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string'  can't be used to index type 'Router'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type     'Router'.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false&target=3&ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAUQB5igUwM4YDRwN5wBKEArjGlLoZpAHYZpwC+cAZlBCHAORorpZuAbgBQI4LXJRWAQwDGjYmUZ4RcdXDAyYACwBccDDCgSA5qI1wQaXRAAmBoydrm1GnTNp2ANhQMAxElo5GGAIWgsNEGA7HzQAdxl0AKCQsNo4AB84ILs0Vgk0O1EmMTlwozhvCFM4AF44AAoBA2oMOgYASnqAPjhy+ghfADpq02bMTtERAcqOZQxW0nIAbQBdergVt3VVS0stXQMAIgB6HU40Y+wd-etbBzhj0xtr28sPL18oAwnFohoFTQ3TqfQEwwYXka3AA8gBpbidG77KIxOKJZJVGq3JjIjR7FGabT6J6nchGK54lH3C6PZ6vKn7T5xH5NFoA9pAkFgzAQtBQ7gAFUwMBkdggiMZlmisV8GLQBjGOJEazKFXg8ykS2UUE2yFQmAwwyUUkaUzEmt5IBkYGay0YoNuduUwxl6KSwNuAH44JaoCtLa6bLS1s7yMNDjpcIHmd9o-bXWi5R7OrcDH6AwmafZQ4HI-GXbGKKnOkA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está obtendo essa mensagem porque está compilado seu código com a opção [`--noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) que força o *TypeScript* a disparar uma exceção em declarações e expressões onde o tipo `any` é implícito.

O [express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express) é uma biblioteca escrita em *JavaScript*, que é uma linguagem conhecida por não impor restrições de tipo. No *TypeScript* é diferente a linguagem é um superconjunto fortemente tipificado do *JavaScript*.
Quando tenta indexar `router[route.method]`, para usar rotas cujo os nomes são inválidos no *Javascript/TypeScript*, o *TypeScript* implicitamente converte o `string route.method` no typo `any` pois o objeto `const router: Router = Express.Router();`foi escrito em *JavaScript* que não dispões do mecanismo de assinatura de índices presente no *TypeScript*.

Para corrigir basta remover ou setar a opção `--noImplicitAny` como `false`.

No *Playground* vá em Config e desabilite a opção `noImplicitAny`.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit:**

Como dito nos comentários outra possibilidade é manter a opção `noImplicitAny` e forçar um cast explicito:

```
routes.map(route =>
    (route.middleware)
    ? (router as any)[route.method](route.path, route.handler, route.middleware)
    : (router as any)[route.method](route.path, route.handler)
)
```

Comment: Mas n tem outra forma, sem desativar esta opção no tsconfig.json ?

Comment: Essa opção `--noImplicitAny` não é adequada para ligar bibliotecas *JS*. Use-a quando for usar apenas código puro em *TypeScript*.

Comment: Uma outra opção seria utilizar um _cast_ explícito ao `any` somente em `router[route.method as any]`, assim não é necessário desativar a opção para todo o projeto.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Testei no playground continua não suportando.

Comment: Realmente, deveria ter testado antes de comentar, hehe. Se fizer o _cast_ na instância do _router_ funciona: `(router as any)[route.method]`.